# Ms Access how to convert a string HH:MM to numbers or time for calculation

Tags: ms-access

in my ms access query i have a column named [Hours & Minutes]. the column values are taken as "(((tblA.TotalMins) &':'&(mid (tblA.TotalHours,4,2))) as [Hours & Minutes]". it is a string type i want to sum it so i want to convert it into a HH:MM format for calculation or any format for calculation

Answer (score 0):

Your expression doesn't make sense, as it seems to interchange *hours:minutes* to *minuttes:hours*.

If your field holds text like `"22:45"`, this can easily be converted:

```
DateValue([TextTime]) As TrueTime
```

If you have a field for hours and another for minutes, use *TimeSerial*:

```
TimeSerial([TotalHours],[TotalMinutes],0) As TrueTime
```